# create new dataframe based on 2 columns

Tags: r

I have a large dataset "totaldata" containing multiple rows relating to each animal. Some of them are LactationNo 1 readings, and others are LactationNo 2 readings. I want to extract all animals that have readings from both LactationNo 1 and LactationNo 2 and store them in another dataframe "lactboth"
There are 16 other columns of variables of varying types in each row that I need to preserve in the new dataframe.
I have tried merge, aggregate and %in%, but perhaps I'm using them incorrectly eg.

```
(lactboth <- totaldata[totaldata$LactationNo %in% c(1,2), ])
```

*Animal Id* is column *1*, and *lactationno* is column *2*. I can't figure out how to select only those AnimalId with LactationNo=1&2

Have also tried

```
lactboth <- totaldata[ which(totaldata$LactationNo==1 & totaldata$LactationNo ==2), ]
```

I feel like this should be simple, but couldn't find an example to follow quite the same. Help appreciated!!

Comment: `totaldata[totaldata$LactationNo %in% c(1,2), "AnimalId"]` perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then your dataset looks something like this:

```
  AnimalId LactationNo
1        A           1
2        B           2
3        E           2
4        A           2
5        E           2
```

and you'd like to select animals that happen to have both lactation numbers 1 & 2 (like A in this particular example). If that's the case, then you can simply use merge:

```
lactboth <- merge(totaldata[totaldata$LactationNo == 1,],
                  totaldata[totaldata$LactationNo == 2,], 
                  by.x="AnimalId", 
                  by.y="AnimalId")[,"AnimalId"]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. You are right about what my dataset looks like. Both the suggestions made have a strange effect- when I dim(lactboth) R returns "NULL"  and fix(lactboth) gives a strange output which is no longer in a table and is a comma separated list of AnimalID with "L" written after each AnimalID number. Does this fault ring any bells?

Comment: I don't think what you're describing is a fault. My code above returns a vector of the AnimalIDs (hence the `[,"AnimalId"]` at the end) that have both lactation numbers 1 & 2. And if the AnimalIDs in your dataset are integers, R usually denotes integers with an L at the end. Same is true for the behavior you're describing when you use `dim`. `dim` returns `NULL` if you pass it a vector. If you want the complete dataset with all the fields, I suggested you add the following line: `both_data <- totaldata[totaldata$AnimalId %in% lactboth,]`.

Comment: Brill, that works - I hadn't understood that it was changing into a vector. Thanks very much